# How to add a condition to an image pixel call? numpy opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I feel like there should be an easy way to do this but I can not find a solution online. I'm looking for a one liner something pythonic.

I know you can do this:

```
Img[:,:,2]=200
```

but how can you add a condition to this?

```
if Img[:,:,2]<=100: 200
```

or

```
image =[i==100 for i in Img[:,:,2] if i <= 100]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simulate `if a[:,:,2]<=100: 200`, we can use `np.where` -

```
a[:,:,2] = np.where(a[:,:,2] <= 100, 200, a[:,:,2])
```

Or simply use the mask to assign -

```
a[a[:,:,2] <= 100,2] = 200
```

Sample run -

```
In [379]: a
Out[379]: 
array([[[ 78, 134,   7],
        [154,  37, 146],
        [ 39,  95,  13]],

       [[114, 138, 100],
        [175, 198, 148],
        [ 39, 130,  37]]])

In [380]: a[a[:,:,2] <= 100,2] = 200

In [381]: a
Out[381]: 
array([[[ 78, 134, 200],
        [154,  37, 146],
        [ 39,  95, 200]],

       [[114, 138, 200],
        [175, 198, 148],
        [ 39, 130, 200]]])
```